# Loop through results and only show Education once per category

Tags: php, mysql, output

I'm trying to get my queried data outputted properly in my html.

I'm trying to have my set of results outputted so that, each row from the database that matches a specific `Education_ID` and the Education is only showed one time period category (e.g. High school diploma/Ged, Post secondary certificate, etc. )? Currently its showing it multiple times - with "High School Diploma or Ged".

Im looking to try to get High School Diploma or GED, Post Secondary Certificate, etc. showing just once.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an associative array for each education level, and then iterate over each array.

e.g construct your array as follows

```
<?php

  $pathwaySteps_grouped_by_education=array();

  foreach ($pathwaySteps as $step => $paths): 
       $pathwaySteps_grouped_by_education[$paths['Education_ID']][$step]=$paths;
  endforeach; ?>
```

Then iterate over your array as you display records

```
  <?php foreach ($pathwaySteps_grouped_by_education as $education_id=>$pathsgroup): ?>
            <div class="pathway-step 
                <?php #if (count($pathsgroup) == 1) echo 'single'; ?> 
                <?php if ($currentEd == $education_id) echo 'you-are-here'; ?>">
                <div class="pathway-content">
                   <?php $showeducationname=true; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($pathsgroup as $job): ?>
                       <?php if($showeducationname): ?>   
                         <h4><?php echo ucwords($job['Ed_Name']) ?></h4>
                         <?php $showeducationname=false; ?>
                       <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="job">

                            <h5><?php echo $job['GroupName'] ?></h5>

                            <dl>
                                <dt>Entry Wage</dt>
                                <dd><?php echo $job['EntryWage'] ?></dd>
                                <dt>Median Wage</dt>
                                <dd><?php echo $job['MedianWage'] ?></dd>
                                <dt>Job Outlook</dt>
                                <dd><?php echo ucwords($job['Job_Outlook']) ?></dd>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div> <!-- pathway-content -->
            </div> <!-- pathway-step -->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This works well, the issue is, it is repeating the education level multiple times now (see the NEW OUTPUT above)

Comment: I've introduced flag $showeducationname to ensure education level header is displayed once